# How to pass custom fields into mapbox-gl js to create points on map?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, mapbox, advanced-custom-fields

I've created a map using mapbox and plotted multiple custom points that you can interact with. I am also using Wordpress and want to use advanced custom fields to create each point so they can easily be managed from a non-technical person. The fields are all setup, but I am having trouble passing them into the javascript in my php template.

I've tried using a loop but I can't use the loop inside javascript. Here is my Mapbox code that I am using to plot the points and want to use advanced custom fields with:

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/coptmarketing/cjvi7hc4602dk1cpgqul6mz0b',
    center: [-76.615573, 39.285685],
    zoom: 16 // starting zoom
});

var geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "title": "Shake Shack",
                "id": "shake-shack"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-76.609844, 39.286894]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "title": "Starbucks",
                "id": "starbucks"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-76.619071, 39.286649]
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

I've stored the data in a JSON array:

```
[{"title":"Shake Shack","slug":"shake-shack","latitude":"-76.609844","longitude":"39.286894"},{"title":"Starbucks","slug":"starbucks","latitude":"-76.619071","longitude":"39.286649"}]
```

How do I insert this into the geoJSON?

Comment: This question feels slightly too vague for me to solve discretely. In the very least, show us the raw output from Wordpress when you grab your data. If I had to do this, I might do it one of two ways: `1.` use Wordpress's native JSON api which it now ships with. `2.` In PHP, loop over the custom fields, build a JSON object which I'll store in the HTML. Then, from the JS, grab the JSON object and insert the GeoJSON

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for some guidance. I'll start with what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

First I created a plugin that stored the custom post data in a JSON array and stored it on the server. This also updated every time I updated, saved or deleted a post. Here is the example JSON:

```
data = {"placeList": [{"title":"Shake Shack","slug":"shake-shack","latitude":"-76.609844","longitude":"39.286894"},{"title":"Starbucks","slug":"starbucks","latitude":"-76.619071","longitude":"39.286649"}]}
```

Then in the php file, I called the .json file and in my javascript, inserted the array into the GeoJSON:

```
var placeJson = data;

        var geojson = {
          type: "FeatureCollection",
          features: [],
        };

        for (i = 0; i < placeJson.placeList.length; i++) {

          geojson.features.push({
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [placeJson.placeList[i].latitude, placeJson.placeList[i].longitude]
            },
            "properties": {
              "id": placeJson.placeList[i].slug,
              "title": placeJson.placeList[i].title
            }
          });
        }
```